# How to use Rails connection which is manually checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have code which where I manually checkout a connection like

`connection = User.connection_pool.checkout`

Now, I wish to use this connection to query any record in DB

is there a way to achieve this.

I'm not sure what I'm suppose to do with the connection, I just obtained other then checking it back in

So ideally I want the code do this.

```
  connection = User.connection_pool.checkout
  ... ## query

  User.connection_pool.checkin(connection)
```

**Note**: Please don't answer me to use `with_connection`, the point of this question is to manage checkout/checkin manually.

Any clue ??

Comment: its been 8 years! can you share what has worked with you ?!

Answer (score 0):

Well in Rails 4.2 the way to achieve this is ..

```
connection = User.connection_pool.checkout

User.connection_pool.instance_variable_get(:'@reserved_connections')[Thread.current.object_id] ||= conn

User.first

User.connection_pool.checkin(conn)
```

This Works.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = Model.connection_pool.checkout
@records = conn.execute("call some_stored_procedure(args)")
Model.connection_pool.checkin(conn)
```

I specifically gave the example of executing a stored procedure because no other methods were able to execute SPs. This question actually helped my task out!

You can also execute other queries as well, like:

```
conn.execute("select attr1, attr2 from models")
```